# How to find the cause that makes my App get slower and slower with every click?

Tags: android, performance

Sorry for my poor English.
In my app, I have an `OverviewActivity` with several tables, shown in a GridView.
Every table is a real table in a restaurant (POS app).

When the user clicks on a table, I replace the `OverViewFragment` which is placed in a `FrameLayout` in the `OverviewActivity`, with the `SingleTableFragment`. When the user clicks back, I again replace the `SingleTableFragment` with the `OverViewFragment`.

Now my problem is, that when you click on a table and go back, click on a table and go back, click on a table and go back, again and again, the `SingleTableFragment` loads slower and slower until it completely hangs.

The profiler in Android Studio shows me that the app uses up to 1.5GB of RAM. I've tried to solve this by unset every listener, remove every observer from `LiveData` objects, clear the `ViewModel` from the `SingleTableFragment` and set every variable to `null` in the `onStop` method of `SingleTableFragment`. Where should I start to solve this issue?

Update:
It's possible to switch the `SingleTableFragment's`layout between `buttonLayout` and `listLayout` in the preferences. The problem occures only with the `buttonLayout`, not with the `listLayout`. The Fragment is the same. In its `onCreate` method i check which layout xml file to load. That's why i think it's not because of the fragmenttransaction. But my programming knowledge is not so good :)
Thats how i load the `SingleTableFragment`:

```
    public void loadTableFragment(final String tableAction, final String customerName) {
    int tableNr = 0;
    try {
        tableNr = Integer.parseInt(tableAction);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {
    }
    if (tableNr < 1) {
        M.showToast(this, "wrong Tablenr.!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    } else {
        if (getWindow().getCurrentFocus() != null) {
            HideKeyboard(getWindow().getCurrentFocus(), OverviewActivity.this);
        }
        if (mSingleTableFragment == null) {
            mSingleTableFragment = new SingleTableFragment();
            mSingleTableFragment.setTableValues(mOverviewViewModel, mMainTableViewModel, mOverview_OpenOrdersFragment_ViewModel, mOverview_RoomsFragment_ViewModel);
        }
        mSingleTableFragment.setTabLayout(mRooms_tab_layout);
        mMainTableViewModel.setTableAction(tableAction);
        mIv_rooms_new.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (mOverviewViewModel.getGKSUserSettings().getMOrder() == 0) {
            hideOrderOptionIcons();
        }else{
            showOrderOptionIcons();
        }
        mMainTableViewModel.setReloadOrder(false);
        mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fl_overview_placeholder, mSingleTableFragment, "tableLayout");
        mFragmentTransaction.commit();

        mOverviewViewModel.setActiveFragment("tableLayout");
        setTableButton(tableAction, customerName);
        hideBottomToolbar();
        mOverviewRoomsFragment.stopTableUpdate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the code you use to replace the fragment.

Comment: Without code, we cannot see exactly what is going on. If it appears the RAM usage rises each time you click a table and go back, I believe you keep a reference to the clicked tables. The garbage collector of Java then cannot free the ram the table is using. Could you show the code for what happens when you click a table?